# Hive optimizer not performing well for joins involving partitioned tables

Tags: sql, database, hadoop, hive, bigdata

I am using Hive version 0.7.1-cdh3u2

I have two big tables (let's say) A and B, both partitioned by day. I am running the following query

```
select col1,col2
from A join B on (A.day=B.day and A.key=B.key)
where A.day='2014-02-25'
```

When I look at the xml file of the map reduce task, I find that mapred.input.dir includes A/2014-02-25 and all hdfs directories for all days for B rather than only for the specific day ('2014-02-25'). This takes a lot of time and more number of reduce tasks.

I also tried to use

```
select col1,col2
from A join B on (A.day=B.day and A.key=B.key and A.day='2014-02-25'
                  and B.day='2014-02-25')
```

This query performed much faster and with only the required hdfs directories in mapred.input.dir

I have the following questions.

1. Shouldn't hive optimizer be smart enough for both the queries to run exactly in the same manner?
2. What should be an optimized way to run the hive query for joining such tables with partitions on multiple keys?
3. What is the difference between using conditions that involve partitions in the join on clause and the  where clause in terms of performance?

Comment: Hive 0.7.1 is extremely old release, consider upgrading and retrying your queries.

Answer (score 4):

You need to mention the condition i.e the partition directory explicitly in the JOIN clause or in the WHERE clause. So it will process only the required partitions which will in turn increase the performance.

You can refer this link:
[Apache Hive LanguageManual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-PartitionBasedQueries)